# Make embedded Spring Cloud Config Server with sub-context-path

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-boot-admin, spring-cloud-config-server

In order to have a Spring Cloud Config Server / Spring Boot Admin all-in-one combo, I'd need to declare a global subpath for the config server API as I did with Spring Boot Admin's one (spring.boot.admin.context-path=/dashboard). I could find no context-path changer equivalent for the config server, and its API is obviously interfering with my attempts to isolate them.
I could of course use separate projects, but before that I'd like to check I didn't miss any feature around.
Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
spring.cloud.config.server.prefix=/service
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the config server equivalent (to be guessed...) : 
    `spring.cloud.config.server.prefix=/service`